# Cleaning up the jQuery in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application and I have all the jQuery scattered out in alot of different views and this is really ugly.I really want the jQuery in one place but when i take some of the jQuery code and move it to the application.js file the jQuery doesnt work or is maybe included last....I really dont know the issue. Can i have some help on the right way to do this ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

1. Ensure you include you 'application.js' file last in your layouts files
2. If the functions require the DOM to load, use '$(document).ready'